# Multiple varying cross section beam with distributed load - FBD Method?

Tags: beam, deflection, bending

Based on the 2 different threads read below :
[Multiple Varying cross section beam deflection](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21902/multiple-varying-cross-section-beam-deflection)
+
[Multiple varying cross section beam with uniform loads](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40052/multiple-varying-cross-section-beam-with-uniform-loads)

I'm trying to set up a calculation sheet (Excel is my friend) for a cantilever beam under uniformly distributed load with the 3 different sections (once I'll get the method right, I want to move to 10 sections). My idea was to use the free body diagram method as mentioned in the linked threads but doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I'm putting my calculations, that would be awesome if someone can tell me where I'm wrong. enter image description here
[image]

I've compared with a beam theory with w, E and I being the same, and the graph is very different, so I'm sure there is something wrong, but can't seem to tell why.

[image]

If you find my mistake, I'll be happy to learn from it.

Many thanks !